# How to insert z values onto x,y coordinates?

Tags: python-3.x

I have three list, which has some repeated values. I am using them as x and y coordinates. Thus, my third list is corresponds to the values that I want to plot as a heatmap.
For now, I can assign the values of z for only one list, how can I make a for loop to do the same for the rest of the grid?

```
x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
y = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
z = [5.9617e-09,6.3562e-09,6.819e-09,7.3562e-09,7.989e-09,8.6735e- 
09,9.3898e-09,1.0139e-08,1.0912e-08,1.0912e-08]

xs = len(set(x))
ys = len(set(y))

grid = []
counter = 0

for row in range(ys):
   rows = [] # creating the rows on the grid
   if len(rows) < ys: # I want to loop over ys and assign the values os z to each coordinate
       grid.append(z[counter])
       counter = counter+1
print(grid)
```

Once I have a 2d array, then I can use the heatmap to plot it nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `numpy`:

```
In [1]: z = [5.9617e-09,6.3562e-09,6.819e-09,7.3562e-09,
             7.989e-09,8.6735e-09,9.3898e-09,1.0139e-08,
             1.0912e-08,1.0912e-08] 

In [2]: len(z)                                                 
Out[2]: 10

In [3]: import numpy as np
```

Ten numbers don't fit in a 3x3 grid, so skip the last one.

```
In [4]: nz = np.array(z[:-1])                                                                            
Out[4]: 
array([5.9617e-09, 6.3562e-09, 6.8190e-09, 7.3562e-09, 7.9890e-09,
       8.6735e-09, 9.3898e-09, 1.0139e-08, 1.0912e-08])

In [5]: nz.reshape((3,3))                                                                                
Out[5]: 
array([[5.9617e-09, 6.3562e-09, 6.8190e-09],
       [7.3562e-09, 7.9890e-09, 8.6735e-09],
       [9.3898e-09, 1.0139e-08, 1.0912e-08]])
```

---

A plain Python solution using `itertools` and `functools`:

```
In [6]: import itertools as it 
   ...: import functools as ft                                                                           

In [7]: def chunked(iterable, n):  # {{{1 
   ...:     def take(n, iterable): 
   ...:         return list(it.islice(iterable, n)) 
   ...:     return iter(ft.partial(take, n, iter(iterable)), []) 
   ...: 

In [8]: list(chunked(z[:-1], 3))                                                                         
Out[8]: 
[[5.9617e-09, 6.3562e-09, 6.819e-09],
 [7.3562e-09, 7.989e-09, 8.6735e-09],
 [9.3898e-09, 1.0139e-08, 1.0912e-08]]
```

Comment: The following is the type of outcome I would like with my set of data.           counter=0
x =[0,1,2]
y = [0,1,2]
data=[[0 for x in range(len(x))] for y in range(len(y))]
print(data)
for i in x:
    for k in y:
        print(i,k)
        data[i][k] = (z[counter])
        counter=counter+1
print(data)                                                                                                                             However, when I try to plugging the data I have,  it gives an error "IndexError: list index out of range". Do you know how I can fix it?